# Prevent "show" action on the URL "/users/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

By default, my web app performs the "show" action on the URL "/users/1".

I have the following route:

```
get    'profile'   => 'users#show'
```

I have authorization set up such that a logged user can look at only his pages. But I also, want to prevent the "show" action on the URL "/users/1". What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit what you have in routes.

```
resources :users, only: [:whatever_action]
```

or

```
resources :users, except: [:show]
```

Comment: I now get the error "No route matches [GET] "/users/5"". Would it be a good idea to just redirect instead? If yes, do you know how I can do that?

Comment: I wouldn't redirect, I simply wouldn't link to that anywhere in the application.  You can use `get 'profile' => 'users#show', as: :profile`.  Then you can use `profile_path` in your links

Comment: If this application is already live, then I'd do a redirect in your http server.